# SAPUI5: Open JSON in new browser window fails

Tags: json, download, sapui5, urlhelper

I would like to download JSON from my app to disk. For this purpose I am retrieving the JSON as encoded string from the backend and using this approach:

```
const uri = `data:text/json,${sJSONContent}`;
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect(uri, true);
```

This opens a new window but nothing is displayed and there is the error "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" displayed in the new window's console.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it out myself. This is how to do it:

```
// it is important to use the "data:" prefix and urlencode the data if necessary!
const sData = `data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${sJSONContent}`;
// create a HTML 'anchor' element
const dummyAnchor = document.createElement('a');
// add the data string as 'target' of that anchor
dummyAnchor.setAttribute('href', sData);
// set the 'download' attribute so that the browser treats the href as to be downloaded
dummyAnchor.setAttribute('download', 'my.json');
// add the dummyAnchor element to the document
document.body.appendChild(dummyAnchor);
// trigger clicking of that anchor element to start the download
dummyAnchor.click();
// remove the dummy again from the document to avoid side effects
dummyAnchor.remove();
```

I hope this will help someone else!